# WS2812B - Response time

Tags: raspberry-pi, delay, led-matrix

I'm working on a project that needs some decor lighting, the lighting need to be able to render objects, so I was thinking of building a 32x16 LED matrix with WS2812B chips, and control it with a Raspberry pi.

But my concern is the response time of the chips. If I connect 512 chips to the bus, the data will be 12kB. And due to the datasheep for the chip, it can transfer 800kbps, with 50μs reset time. So the matrix will have approximately 8 updates per second.

But how long delay will it be between the first and last chip?

Comment: Where's the hyperlink to your "datasheep"?

Comment: @Transistor has given you the right answer. But 15mS is still enough that if you scroll a marquee rapidly you might see the text leaning. If you organised your LEDs into a x8 wide array and fed them 64 frames instead of 512 then that would reduce the time to 1/8th of that, but it would widen your electrical connection considerably.

Answer (score 1):

Are you mixing up bits and bytes?

From the [WS2812B datasheet](http://www.seeedstudio.com/document/pdf/WS2812B%20Datasheet.pdf):

- Each frame is 24 bits.
- Each bit takes 1.25 µs.
- You have 512 frames.
- At the end of the transmission you need a 50 µs reset code.

\$ t = 24 \times 1.25\mu \times 512 + 50\mu = 15.410 \ \mathrm {ms} \$

Refresh rate = \$ \frac {1}{15.41m} = 65 \$ updates per second.

Comment: My bad, you are right. I mixed up bits and bytes. So it takes 15.410ms from the first LED lights up until the last lights up? That's not so bad.

Comment: If that solves the problem then please accept the best answer (after a day or two to give others a chance to answer) to indicate the correct solution to future readers. Thanks.